# How do I collect metrics on the VMs running in my Hyper-V cluster?

Tags: hyper-v, performance-monitoring

I have a Hyper-V cluster on two physical machines.  I have a small pile of VMs running on that cluster of varying operating systems.  I am trying to collect operating metrics for the VMs so that we can have some visibility into what is happening in there.

The things I am interested in are things like disk IO and CPU usage.  Ideally I would be able to monitor things like memory usage and swapping, CPU states (IO-wait verses working) and the like.

Traditionally I have installed SNMP clients on the VMs and monitored each VM as if it was a physical computer.  However I have been reading that one shouldn't monitor VMs directly, one should try to do it through the hypervisor host instead.

Is there a better way to collect running metrics from my VMs on this cluster?

Comment: the most correct thing to do is both host and guest level monitoring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is some excellent information about monitoring Hyper-V located here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tvoellm/archive/2009/04/23/monitoring-hyper-v-performance.aspx

Comment: No problem it helped me a lot in the past